# Specify default value for ASP MVC 3 DropDownListFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, html.dropdownlistfor, dropdownlistfor

I've done this a hundred times but not sure what is going on here. I have a `DropDownListFor` that I populate in the controller like so

```
        var mktsegments = from p in db.ChannelMarketSegment
                          where (p.ChannelCode != "0")
                          select p;
        ViewBag.Pendist = new SelectList(mktsegments, "Pendist", "Pendist");
```

And in the view, I am attempting to set the default value of this drop down list with the `Pendist` value.

**EDIT:**  Pendist is a field that exists in each item pulled into `mktsegments` via the `Linq` query.

```
    <div class="M-editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Pendist)<span class="req">*</span>
    </div>
    <div class="M-editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Pendist,
         (SelectList)ViewBag.Pendist, new { onchange = "ChangeChannel()" }) 
    </div>
```

However, all this does is set the first value in the list as the default value. If I try to add `model => model.Pendist` or `Model.Pendist` as the third paramter in the `DropDownListFor` like this

```
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Pendist,
      (SelectList)ViewBag.Pendist, model => model.Pendist, new { onchange = "ChangeChannel()" })
```

I either get the following errors

(for `model => model.Pendist`)

`Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type`

(for `Model.Pendist`)

`'Model' confilcts with the declaration 'System.Web.Mcv.WebViewPage<TModel>.Model'`

Comment: Is `Pendist` a list of objects or the value that needs to be selected???

Comment: `Pendist` is a field contained in each item in `mktsegments`, I'll add that info the post. Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are conflicting with the MVC ModelState.  When creating Drow down lists, make sure that your property that holds the selected value is not named the same thing as your list of objects.  Also, do not use a lambda for the default value, but rather just use the model item directly.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Pendist, (SelectList)ViewBag.PendistList, 
    Model.Pendist, new { onchange = "ChangeChannel()" })
```